# Prefill form input on load

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a form and I am trying to prefill one of the input with some URL during page load. However during the form submit the form field submits a null value.

I have tried using Ngmodel:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="_onSubmit(f)">
  <!-- <div>{{ formItems?.length }}</div> -->
  <div *ngFor="let i of formItems">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
      <input
        [name]="i.name"
        attr.name="{{ i.name }}"
        [(ngModel)]="referreURL"
        [type]="i.type"
        [placeholder]="i.label"
        required=""
        class="form-control"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Below I have on my type script file.

```
referreURL: string = document.referrer;
```

Comment: Can you add the ts file?

Answer (score 0):

you can add **if statement** to wait for load date form URL(Service)

```
<form ng-if="formItems" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="_onSubmit(f)">
        <!-- <div>{{ formItems?.length }}</div> -->
   <div *ngFor="let i of formItems">

       <div  class="form-group" style="display:none">
                <input [name]="i.name" attr.name="{{i.name}}" [(ngModel)]="referreURL"
                    [type]="i.type" [placeholder]="i.label" required=""
                    class="form-control">
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Hope This will helps.. !

Answer (score 0):

update once data is loaded using *ngIf

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="_onSubmit(f)" *ngIf="formItems">
    <div *ngFor="let i of formItems">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
            <input
            [name]="i.name"
            attr.name="{{ i.name }}"
            [(ngModel)]="referreURL"
            [type]="i.type"
            [placeholder]="i.label"
            required=""
            class="form-control"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```